# Connecting MPU6050 to Arduino Lilypad

Tags: sensors, hardware, mpu6050, hc-05

To preface, I am very new to Arduino and I watched [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lVqAu-p6wq0&list=PLBxj6rgFwv2ts4rFV6_Rb2Kitxa-ZP4Ox&index=3&t=10s) on YouTube.

It shows how you can build a motion controlled car with Arduino and I decided to make this for my school project.

One thing I am having difficulty with is connecting the MPU6050 to the Lilypad. In the video he doesn't really show much of it and just sticks it onto the board.

However, do I need to solder the MPU6050? Where do I solder the pins the underside or the top. Do I need to align the pins with that of the Lilypad?

Sorry if it's a stupid question I genuinely don't know.

The current condition of our lilypad:
[image: Our lilypad]

What it's supposed to look like:
[image: What it looks like in the video]

If you see the images, in addition to the yellow light of the MPU 6050 and the red light of the HC 05, the red light of the Lilypad is also supposed to light up like the second picture, however in ours, only the MPU 6050 and the HC 05 lights up and not the Lilypad.

Comment: In [This tutorial](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/) explains how to connect MPU6050 to an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to need some orientation, I will explain a few things, to get you started.

The MPU6050 is a device, that communicates through the I2C interface. It uses 2 communication lines (SCL for the clock and SDA for the data). To use is with the Lilypad, you have to connect those two lines, Vcc (5V) and Ground. If you look at a pinout diagram, you can identify, which of the pads are SDA and SCL on the Lilypad.

It is up to you, if you connect the mentioned lines via soldering or by other means. Normally you would solder connecting wires between the MPU6050 and the Lilypad. If you want the MPU to be removable, you can solder a cable with a pin header (for example female) to the Lilypad and the according pins to the MPU (for example a male pin header). That way, you could also stick the MPU to the board and remove it again if necessary. How you are doing it is not important, as long as the electrical contact is good.

---

There are also a lot of tutorials and ready to use libraries for the MPU6050 on the net. newbie already posted a link to a tutorial. Also Adafruit has a library on [github](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MPU6050) with examples, that explain how to use it. That way you should be able to get started with your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help but there is still a problem, can you please check the images that I uploaded above? The LED of the Lilypad is not lighting up even though the other two are and I'm very confused. I already connected the Lilypad and the MPU 6050 like you said with female jumpers and pin headers.

Comment: Edit: I briefly used a 9V battery, is that a problem? Also, I haven't uploaded the code into theLilypad

Comment: A 9V block battery is not a good choice, because it can only provide low current (it is only meant for low current applications). Better a series of AA batteries or a LiPo pack (though I don't have much experience with this)